# Log table Schema changes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, triggers

Is there any way to log the changes made in `Schema` of a `Table` whenever I do the schema changes?

I was reading an article here about **[DDL Triggers](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-ddl-triggers-in-sql-server-2005-to-capture-schema-changes)**.  But it does not tell about the specific changes made in schema of a table.

Comment: This is a deployment issue, but the obvious answer is that the old and new versions of the DDL script should be in source control, where you can easily diff them and review comments about the change. If that doesn't help, you'll need to clarify how you make changes to the schema, i.e. using which tools?

Comment: Like, Whenever in SSMS, I make change in table design. on saving a table design, should call the trigger to log the changes made.

Comment: Whats about event notifications?

Answer (score 1):

this would be very difficult as quite often in SSMS the table is actually dropped and rebuilt in the background (depending on the complexity of the schema change & whether or not you enabled the "Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created " option in SSMS) - logging all the different types of changes would be a nightmare. (constraints being dropped, only to be re-created - bulk re-inserts, renames etc when all you might have done is re-arranged columns in joined table)

If you're serious about tracking schema changes i'd strongly recommend you script the schema (using the generate scripts option in MSSMS) & check the resulting file into SVN / SourceSafe / TFS & use the many comparison tools available for those systems.

OR, you can use 3rd party products that do all this for you, such as Red Gates SQL Source Control:

http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-source-control/

**Edit: You may find this useful - it makes use of the Service Broker (SQL 2005+) and SSB queues:**

http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2121/event-notifications-in-sql-server-for-tracking-changes/

Answer (score 1):

For this issue i would probably use [Event Notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189453.aspx). Although DDL trigger's in my opinion do tell about specific changes made to table, just trigger definition:

```
Create Trigger tr_DDLNotikums
    On DataBase
For **DDL_DATABASE_LEVEL_EVENTS**
```

Answer (score 0):

Use DDL Trigger In Below Format

```
 CREATE TRIGGER tr_DDL_Database ON DATABASE 
 FOR DDL_SCHEMA_EVENTS
 AS Begin
   Insert Into LogTable (XmlColumn)
   SELECT EVENTDATA()
 End
```