# SQL Server 2008 table change (insert/update/delete) notification push on broker

Tags: sql-server-2008, notifications, publish-subscribe, service-broker

I have a rather complex and large database with about 3000+ objects (tables/triggers/sps combined). I inherited this DB and restructuring it is probably 3-4 years away.
meanwhile, I need to implement a pub sub feature for any insert/update/delete on these tables. Given number of tables and existing queries *probably* query notification (and SQL Dependency) will not work. What I am looking for is a way to push the changes (what changed in table - like records PK and table name) on the service broker so I can use external activator to then retrieve change,and then use my custom pub sub from that point onwards.

I have pretty much all the ducks lined up except for the way to push change notification on service broker.

Any help/pointers are appreciated.
Thanks.
N M
PS. I did look around for similar postings and did come across a few however, MSDN articles they referred to seem to have all removed  - not sure what's going on on MSDN site.

Answer (score 1):

For external activator look at [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8824)- "Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Broker External Activator".

For console application (that processes messages) great idea is to drop an eye in [codeplex](http://msftsbprodsamples.codeplex.com/). There is good examples.

To put event notification (notifications, that will be used by external activator service) code looks something like this:

```
Create Queue ExternalActivatorQueue;
Create Service ExternalActivatorService On Queue ExternalActivatorQueue
([http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQL/Notifications/PostEventNotification])

Create Event Notification NotifyExternalActivator
On Queue dbo.ProcessQueue
For QUEUE_ACTIVATION
To Service 'ExternalActivatorService', 'current database'
```

To send message in the queue:

```
    Declare @h UniqueIdentifier;
    Declare @x xml = '<tag/>';
    Begin Dialog Conversation @h
    From Service MyTableService
        To Service 'ProcessService'
    With Encryption = OFF;

    Send On Conversation @h(@x)
```

All steps i done to make it work is [here](http://www.sqlblog.lv/2012/03/service-broker-areja-aktivizacija.html), but just in Latvian :). There actually is almost what you need (trigger that sends messages when data are inserted in table..).

Comment: Janis, thanks for the quick response. Actually I had gathered these steps already from Service broker team's blog. My confusion is to generate the initial push on the broker itself. How do I configure it to generate a notification when say an insert happens in one of the tables. As I mentioned, broker onwards the whole chain is pretty much clear to me (would appreciate if there were any code segments to ride on, however, that is not the problem). Just the initial push on SB is where I am getting lost. Query notification did not seem a good way to push message/generate notification in my case.

Comment: @Janis - can you look into this similar issue http://stackoverflow.com/q/10599616/1379794