# live ticker in c# without using a web service

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, events

I have a WPF ticker control that gets data and displays it. I have to make it live by updating it when ever there is a change in the corresponding table in the DB.
 I cannot use WCF services. I want to know whether I can watch a particular table for changes and bubble those events to my WPF form? I am using `SQL SERVER 2008`.

Comment: what is meant by "live"?  How stale can the data be?  The answer to that question will dictate what you have to do.

Comment: You can use a timer to check the timestamp column of the table and its row and upon your conditions apply operations on data and ticker

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server 2008 table change (insert/update/delete) notification push on broker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10603041/sql-server-2008-table-change-insert-update-delete-notification-push-on-broker)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never tried this before but this may help you achieve what you are trying to do.

[Using SqlDependency in a Windows Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a52dhwx7%28VS.80%29.aspx)