# How do I optimize database polling

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, architecture, polling

There is legacy solution where 2 applications communicate with each other via SQL Server 2008 R2 database table.

Application "A" inserts information to database table from time to time 
Application "B" polls database once per second to find out new records

I guess there may be more sophisicated approach how application "B" finds out when new records appear.

Comment: [Service broker?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10603041/562459) Also see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/877273/562459).

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on many things that are not explicitly stated in your question. Is that for one table only? For a limited set of tables? For all tables? Do you have full control on both applications?

Let's suppose this is for one table only and you can't modify A application because you don't control its sources. One way would be to use a [message queue](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/555070) like described here combined to a trigger on that table.

If you control both applications, don't use the database as a singleton an go for message queues directly ...